# Bluetooth mobile streaming/hotspot functionality

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I'm wondering what would be the best way to make use of bluetooth functionality:

1) Is it possible to turn on/use bluetooth function from an app (ios/android)? if so how?

2) What would be the best way to enable broadcasting of bluetooth signal? For instance, is it possible to give a "welcome page" to anyone connecting to a phone from bluetooth?

PS Im wondering also about MFI. Does this mean that only MFI devices can "read" each other, or could an android device read the welcome page of an ios device?

cheers

K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bluetooth, the answer is no for iOS on all questions.

For bluetooth on Android, the answer is yes to both questions. The android bluetooth documentation has step-by-step instructions for each process of bluetooth.

Here's the link to the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#Permissions